# mkdir error : can not create directory ; file exists gitbash

Tags: shell, copy, mkdir, git-shell

#Please help me if you can

I am working on a project where I need to run a program (script file)  from github into git bash terminal. Whenever I tried to run the program, it shows mkdir error, says : mkdir: can not create directory;file exists. I tried to remove any hidden files. No file is there but still it's showing the same error. The program is running in the background and showing the folder running that should be created with mkdir. But after the whole program finish running, i don't find that folder also.

[image]

Comment: (1) Please explain what this has to do with the R programming language (i.e., why the [tag:r] tag). (2) The script is making a directory that already exists, and does not do return-value checking. Either (a) move `last` out of the way yourself, or (b) fix the script. Without seeing the script, I don't know how we can help.

Comment: I also used R git terminal. Same problem shows there.

Comment: https://github.com/keke529/IPAM/blob/main/IPAM.files/IPAM.code/IPAM_3

Comment: "R git terminal" means you are running a shell command and shell script inside of an IDE. The only tie to the R programming language is that you are doing it in RStudio, an IDE that coincidentally does a lot of things with R. Even if you called this from R's `base::system(..)`, unless R's function was breaking it and it worked otherwise, _this has nothing to do with the R programming language_. If you run this in a shell terminal (_not_ the RStudio IDE), does it behave any differently, or does it err there as well?

Comment: Similarly, unless this behaves differently in not-git-shell than in git-shell, that tag is also not needed here.